# Как сделать добавление записи в базу данных по таймеру?

Tags: php, mysql

Нужен файл, который будет добавлять в таблицу запись по таймеру. Так вот, каким образом можно это сделать? Знаю, что для этого можно использовать CronTab. В mysql и PHP особо не силен.

Comment: Что такое «определенный момент»? Раз в минуту, каждые 5 минут, раз в час? Либо условие не связанное с временем? Почему файл должен называться cron.php? Это требование какой-то CMS и файл с таким  имен уже вставлен в системный cron? Если запустить этот скрипт без всяких кронов, он работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам. Запускаю cron.php `/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://site.ru/cron/cron.php`. Создал два файла - cron.php и config.php. config.php - файл конфигурации, cron.php - исполняющий указанный код.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать примерно следующее:

1. Настроить системный cron вашего сервера на вызов некого скрипта, например `cron.php`
2. Внутри скрипта `cron.php` проверить текущее время и выполнить все необходимые действия

Можно поступить немного иначе, определить интервалы в самом cron, а в скрипте PHP лишь выполнять определенные действия, связанные с конкретными интервалами. Я решил задачу периодического сбора погоды по филиалам (через каждые 3 часа) и ежемесячного расчета начислений (в начале каждого месяца) и написал что-то вроде этого:

```
<?php

require_once("include/include.inc.php");

if (!api_RunningInCli()) {
    die('Script must be called only from CLI, exited');
}

if ($argc <= 1) {
    die('No parameters, exited');
}

if ($argc > 1 && isset($argv[1])) {
    $period = trim($argv[1]);
    switch ($period) {
        case 'hourly':
            Cron::Hourly();
            break;
        case 'daily':
            Cron::Daily();
            break;
        case 'weekly':
            Cron::Weekly();
            break;
        case 'monthly':
            Cron::Monthly();
            break;
    }
}

?>
```

В **пользовательском** классе Cron статически определены периоды в виде методов, внутри - произвольные действия.

Обратите внимание на то, что скрипт `cron.php` ожидает в параметре указания периода, в моем случае это строки `hourly/daily/weekly/monthly`, поставьте свою строку и свой период, если нужно.

Функция `api_RunningInCli()` защищает скрипт от вызова через браузер, полезно в случае, если это возможно, определена довольно просто:

```
/* Возвращает true, если скрипт запущен из консоли */
function api_RunningInCli()
{
    return PHP_SAPI == 'cli' || (!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) && !isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
}
```

На оригинальность даже не претендую.

Системный cron в данном случае настроим на периоды и параметр. Содержимое `crontab -l` может быть примерно таким:

```
0 * * * * /path/cron.sh hourly > /dev/null 2>&1
0 0 * * * /path/cron.sh daily > /dev/null 2>&1
0 0 * * 1 /path/cron.sh weekly > /dev/null 2>&1
0 0 1 * * /path/cron.sh monthly > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Хорошо видно настройку периодов cron, абсолютный путь до скрипта SHELL и параметр скрипта. Отдельный скрипт SHELL делать не обязательно, внутри него все крайне просто:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/html
php ./cron.php $1
```

Я сделал скрипт SHELL для того, чтобы было удобно переносить cron.php и вызывать сразу несколько подобных cron.php для всех проектов на одном сервере. Можете от него отказаться без всяких проблем и писать что-то вроде

```
0 * * * * php /var/www/html/cron.php hourly > /dev/null 2>&1
```

в crontab.

Comment: Меня больше интересует сам скрипт. Запускать я умею, меня больше интересует сама начинка. Задача: cron.php который будет раз в 10 секунд добавлять запись в базу данных. `INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
('123','123');`

Comment: cron позволяет делать вызов каждую минуту, меньше не получится. Каждые 10 секунд проще реализовать внутри SHELL скрипта - раз в минуту запускать SHELL скрипт, а внутри делать 6 запусков уже PHP-скрипта. Альтернативный вариант - запустить один раз PHP-скрипт в фоновом режиме из консоли, и внутри него выполнять операции через sleep(10), но это не очень хороший вариант в том плане, что вам будет трудно его обновлять и переносить.

Comment: Вы уверены, что вашу задачу надо решать через периодические действия? В случае вставки записей каждые 10 секунд вы будете иметь по 6 новых записей в минуту, в сутки 6*24*60. Что будет через месяц? Подумайте внимательно, возможно у вас логическая/алгоритмическая ошибка в подходе к задаче, и ее проще решить через установку меток времени последнего события

Comment: мне так и нужно - зафлудить базу данных. Поэтому и получается такой короткий промежуток.